# why is my window.dialogArguments undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, modal-dialog

I need to open up a .aspx page in a modal dialog.  Here is the JS code I use to open the dialog:

```
        if (url) {
            var fullPath = url + "/Validation.aspx";
        }
        else {
            alert("Could not find the location of the merge dialog.  Please contact your System admin and have them update the configuration entity.");
            return;
        }

        var features = "unadorned:yes;scroll:yes;resizable:yes;status:yes;dialogHeight:480px;dialogWidth:480px;";

        var args = {
            selected: selectedIds,
            page: pageIds,
            fetchXml: xml,
            entity: "xyz"
        };

        window.showModalDialog(fullPath, args, features);
```

In my validation.aspx page I need to be able to grab the JS arguments, assign them to hidden fields, then repost, so I can use those arg values server side.

here is my JS code in my .aspx page:

```
window.onload = function(){        
    if (!window.dialogArguments)
        return;

        var args = window.dialogArguments;
        ...
}
```

I have seen tons of examples of this working throughout the web.  **But...My window.dialogArguments is always undefined in my .aspx page.  What gives? anyone have any thoughts or solutions?**

Comment: ps:  here is my JS code in my .aspx page:

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to run that code? Where is the code snippet located, in the document head, the bottom...?

Comment: the JS in the aspx page is in the header.  the window.dialogArguments is undefined, so it just returns out of the window.onload function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My assumption here is that the ASPX dialog page is being opened cross-domain.

This would mean that your parent page is in one domain aka: `http://abc/page.html`, and that your child dialog page is in another domain like: `http://def/dialog.html`.

If this is the case, it seems as though there are restrictions against accessing dialogArguments and returnValue. Check out the comments on [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587892/asp-net-cross-domain-modal-window-window-showmodaldialog-parameter-value-alw) for example.