# I can't get window.dialogArguments

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get window.dialogArguments from modal box but i cant do that :(
I want to display automatically dialogbox when parent-page is loaded. It is ok, when i display dialogbox with userEvent like click but when i display dialogbox when body/window onload, dialogArguments is undefined, Here is my simple code:
ParentPage:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
 function createDialogBox()
 {
  var dialogBox = showModalDialog("in1.html",{"name":"Lucas"})
 }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="createDialogBox();">

    Parent Page

    </body>
    </html>
```

DialogPage:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Modal dialog sample</title>

    <script>
    var arg = window.dialogArguments;
    console.log(arg)// udefined! why?
    </script>
    <body>
    DialogBox Page
    </body>
    </html>
```

Buy if i set eventHandler like onclick on the body everything is ok:
Parent Page:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
 function createDialogBox()
 {
    var dialogBox = showModalDialog("in1.html",{"name":"Lucas"})
 }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    Parent Page
    <button onClick="createDialogBox()">Show Dialog Box</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Where is the problem?
In addition when i load dialog box body.onload, i get in firefox attention but if i load when i click the button attention not display.
I have firefox 49.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038764/why-is-my-window-dialogarguments-undefined

Comment: @prasad `"in1.html"` is obviously on the same domain

Comment: all file are in my local disk ant both are the same folder